# How to find from which row and column the value belong?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.x

Suppose I created the below data frame

```
data = {'Height_1': [4.3,6.7,5.4,6.2], 
        'Height_2': [5.1, 6.9, 5.1, 5.2], 
        'Height_3': [4.9,6.2,6.5,6.4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Suppose someone comes and asks me

1. Find the row and column of height 6.9 ?
2. Find in how many rows and columns height 6.2 is present?

Please help me with what will be the code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas [.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) function to compare all the values of your dataframe to a given value:

```
In [10]: df[df.isin([6.9])]                                                     
Out[10]: 
   Height_1  Height_2  Height_3
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       6.9       NaN
2       NaN       NaN       NaN
3       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Now, if you want to get rows and column directly from it use [.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) on it. So, it will be like:

```
In [11]: df[df.isin([6.9])].stack()                                             
Out[11]: 
1  Height_2    6.9
dtype: float64
```

The output is a series. This will work in case of multiple matches too where the output will be a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you ..I got my output

Comment: You may accept it as the answer if your problem got solved.